# LuaLaTeX: ctex and microtype together produce errors when using "\scshape"

Tags: errors, luatex, microtype, ctex

Consider the following MWE, to compile with LuaLaTeX:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[fontset=fandol]{ctex}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
{\scshape Some text}
\end{document}
```

Without `\usepackage{microtype}`, the code compiles well, but with `microtype` there are a few errors like:

```
Missing font identifier.
<to be read again> 
ltj@curjfnt 
{\scshape
```

```
Missing = inserted for ifnum.
<to be read again> 
ltj@curjfnt 
{\scshape
```

These errors might have been introduced in an update in June or July, and have remained since then.

I'm using TeX Live 2021 with all packages up-to-date (till October). What's going on here and how can I fix this?

**Update:** This problem has been fixed since 2021/11/18, see https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/commit/09e78bc34346daa50be9b5892ed1503550e0f444.

Comment: This seems to be a new problem, in older TeX Live (2019) there are no errors (with or without microtype). There are warnings that `LTJY3/song/m/n` and `LTJY3/FandolSong-Regular(0)/m/sc` are undefined and are both replaced by `LTJY3/song/m/up`, however this still results in correct output for smallcaps.

Comment: notify the ctex and the microtype maintainer. It looks as if ctex is setting up some fonts in a way so that microtype can't use them.

Comment: Apparently, this has been fixed in `ctex` (as of 2021/12/12).

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** in the newest microtype 3.0, one could use the following code as a temporary workaround (here `\AtEndPreamble` requires the package `etoolbox`):

```
\AtEndPreamble{\AtBeginDocument{\microtypesetup{deactivate}{\scshape}\microtypesetup{reactivate}}}
\AtEndPreamble{\AtBeginDocument{\microtypesetup{deactivate}{\bfseries\scshape}\microtypesetup{reactivate}}}
\AtEndPreamble{\AtBeginDocument{\microtypesetup{deactivate}{\sffamily\scshape}\microtypesetup{reactivate}}}
\AtEndPreamble{\AtBeginDocument{\microtypesetup{deactivate}{\ttfamily\scshape}\microtypesetup{reactivate}}}
```

---

**Original post:**

Strangely enough, adding this line to the preamble solves the problem.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\microtypesetup{disable}{\scshape}\microtypesetup{enable}}
```

It is found by accident, and I have no idea why this works.