# How to turn off microtype temporarily?

Tags: microtype

As a temporary workaround for the [conflict between `microtype` and `ctex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609104/194994), I need to disable `microtype` around the command `\scshape`. In old versions, there is a key `disable` for this (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75635)):

```
\microtypesetup{disable}
...
\microtypesetup{enable}
```

However, in the newest version 3.0, this key seems no longer available, yet the documented `activate=false` does not behave the same.

Is there an alternative for the keys `disable` and `enable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old keys `disable` and `enable` are now (in v3.0) called `deactivate` and `reactivate`, respectively. This name change was necessary because the former option `draft` is now called `disable` (so that it's not inherited from the class options).

Note that `de/reactivate` are intentionally *undocumented* because they are only meant to provide a temporary workaround as a last resort in case things go awry, until a real fix is available. (I'm aware of the problem with `ctex`, but I think it's not `microtype`'s fault.)